# Извлечение значений по ключу JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Всем привет, пытаюсь сделать из объекта - перечень ссылок для дальнейшей переборки в цикле.

С помощью:

```js
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('xml/sitemap-10.xml', 'utf8');
parseString(xml, function(err, result) {
    urlList = getValue(result, 'url').value;
});
```

Получается вот такой объект:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее хочу вытащить именно ссылки через цикл:

```js
function getLinks (object, key) {
    for (key in object) {
        return object[key];
    }
}
```

Но выводит только первую ссылку(
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот полностью этот кусок кода:

```js
var urlList = [];

var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('xml/sitemap-10.xml', 'utf8');
parseString(xml, function(err, result) {
    urlList = getValue(result, 'url').value;
});

function getLinks (object, key) {
    for (key in object) {
        return object[key];
    }
}

console.log(getLinks(urlList, 'loc'));
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: а где в вопросе __вызов__ функции `getLinks`?

Comment: Добавил полный кусок кода в вопрос

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Извлечение значений по ключу JS и перевод в массив](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1313589/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d1%83-js-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2)