# Извлечение значений по ключу JS и перевод в массив

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, fs, cheerio

Всем привет, пытаюсь написать цикл в node js для перебора ссылок из массива и дальнейшей их обработки. Столкнулся с проблемой, вот код:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

function getValue(object, key) {
    var result;
    return Object.keys(object).some(function (k) {
        if (k === key) {
            result = { value: object[k] };
            return true;
        }
        if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object' && (result = getValue(object[k], key))) {
            return true;
        }
    }) && result;    
}

var urlList = [];

var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('xml/sitemap-10.xml', 'utf8');
parseString(xml, function(err, result) {
    urlList = getValue(result, 'url').value;
});

function getLinks (object, key) {
    for (key in object) {
        return object[key];
    }
}

console.log(getLinks(urlList, 'loc'));
```

Но получаю только первый элемент в консоль:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам первичный объект выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось - бы получить массив из элементов-ссылок для дальнейшего перебора парсером.

UPD Добавил push для наполнения массива объектами с ссылками, написал цикл для перебора объектов в массиве для вытаскивания значений в этих объектах, но теперь отказывается запускаться с ошибкой: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Вот код

```js
function getValue(object, key) {
    var result;
    return Object.keys(object).some(function (k) {
        if (k === key) {
            result = { value: object[k] };
            return true;
        }
        if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object' && (result = getValue(object[k], key))) {
            return true;
        }
    }) && result;    
}

var urlList = [];
var linkList = [];

function getLinks (array, storage) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        storage.push(Object.values(array.array[i]));
    }
}

var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('xml/sitemap-10.xml', 'utf8');
parseString(xml, function(err, result) {
    urlList.push(getValue(result, 'url').value);
    getLinks (urlList, linkList);
    console.log(linkList);
});
```

UPD2: Скорректировал код по тому как писали в комментариях на:

```js
function getValue(object, key) {
    var result;
    return Object.keys(object).some(function (k) {
        if (k === key) {
            result = { value: object[k] };
            return true;
        }
        if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object' && (result = getValue(object[k], key))) {
            return true;
        }
    }) && result;    
}

var urlList = [];
var linkList = [];

function getLinks (array, result) {
        result = array.map(({ val }) => val);
    };

var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('xml/sitemap-10.xml', 'utf8');
parseString(xml, function(err, result) {
    urlList.push(getValue(result, 'url').value);
    getLinks (urlList, linkList);
    console.log(linkList);
});
```

Теперь выдаёт:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD3: Странная ситуация, ругается на await и пишет что функция не асинхронная, хотя в вашем коде она явно указана как асинхронная

```js
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const { default: axios } = require('axios');
const { parseStringPromise } = require('xml2js');

const LinkList = await getLinks('https://leroymerlin.ru/sitemap-10.xml')
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);

async function getLinks(url) {
  const { data: sitemapData } = await axios.get(url);
  const parsedSitemapData = await parseStringPromise(sitemapData);

  const items = parsedSitemapData?.urlset?.url;
  if (items) {
    return (Array.isArray(items) ? items : [items]).map(
      (x) => x.loc || []
    ).flat();
  }
}

let parsedItems = {};

const parse = async () => {
    const getHTML = async (url) => {
        const {data} = await axios.get(url);
        return cheerio.load(data);
    }

    const $ = await getHTML(LinkList[1]);
    const title = await $('h1[class=header-2]').html();
    const price = await $('span[slot=price]').html();
    const brand = await $('dt:contains("Марка")').next().html().trim();

    parsedItems.push({title,price,brand});
    console.log(parsedItems);       
}

parse();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Первая ошибка тут: `urlList = getValue(result, 'url').value;` вы не пополняете массив, а перетираете каждый раз. Вторая тут: `for (key in object) { return object[key];` если вы хотите получить больше одного элемента, то здесь видимо нужен фильтр, а не возврат первого найденного элемента

Comment: Первую ошибку можно полечить если значения отправлять в массив с помощью push ?

Comment: Верно, нужен push

Comment: Добавил push и написал цикл перебора объектов в массиве, дополнил вопрос данными

Comment: какой-то бардак, я так понял нужно перебрать масив объектов и вернуть стринги ссылок? зачем (почему) some используется? `result = array.map(({ val }) => val)`

Comment: Ошибку не выдаёт но результат на скриншоте в вопросе

Comment: уфф, у вас getlinks не возвращает ничего, result на входе ему не нужен, думаю вам стоит какой-то базовый курс по js пройти, `const getLinks = array => array.map(({ val }) => val);`

Answer (score 1):

```
const { default: axios } = require('axios');
const { parseStringPromise } = require('xml2js');

getLinks('https://leroymerlin.ru/sitemap-10.xml')
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);

async function getLinks(url) {
  const { data: sitemapData } = await axios.get(url);
  const parsedSitemapData = await parseStringPromise(sitemapData);

  const items = parsedSitemapData?.urlset?.url;
  if (items) {
    return (Array.isArray(items) ? items : [items]).map(
      (x) => x.loc || []
    ).flat();
  }
}
```

Результат запуска:

```bsh
$ node src/xml-parse-1/index.js 
[
  'https://leroymerlin.ru/product/kartina-na-holste-russkaya-kollekciya-feericheskiy-moment-hv-h81-93859335/',
  'https://leroymerlin.ru/product/kartina-na-holste-russkaya-kollekciya-zhelannoe-hv-h76-93859334/',
  'https://leroymerlin.ru/product/pled-doco-dante-10184-154-93859290/',
  'https://leroymerlin.ru/product/polotence-bannoe-stenova-home-surf-16515-93859296/',
  ...
]
```

<sub>Загрузку файла `axios` можно заменить на ваш вызов `readFileSync`.</sub>

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрый человек) А как можно обратиться с полученному массиву ссылок ? Я так понял результат функция пушит в консоль не записывая в переменную ?

Comment: `const массивСсылок = await getLinks('https://leroymerlin.ru/sitemap-10.xml')`

Comment: Обновил вопрос, node js почему то теперь ругается на await(

Comment: бесконечное обновление вопроса не приветствуется на stackoverflow. ответ на заданный вопрос был дан. ответ на вопрос, который вы задаёте сейчас: "думаю вам стоит какой-то базовый курс по js пройти"

Comment: Спасибо, так и поступлю)